# Python how to compare the elements in 2 arrays by row

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python,
here's an example:

```
a = array ([[4,7,8],
            [8,8,8],
            [5,8,4]]) 
b = array([[1,1,7],
           [2,6,9],
           [2,3,4]])
the output would be [1,1,0]
```

I want to compare how many elements in b's first row is bigger than the elements in a's first row first elements. And apply the same comparison to every row. The comparison has to be the same row in 2 arrays.The original data shape as(297,6940).Is there any easy way to do with this?Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood good, but I did a example to try explain it to you:

https://repl.it/@Gilles_Medeiros/CompareElementsArray

You'll iterate on first array and compare each first element of the row with all elements in the row in the second array. It's not the best solution, but it's easy to understand.

Comment: No problem. If you have any question, ask me or send me a email. Cya.

Comment: An explicit `for` loop is not recommended when working with NumPy arrays. You should use a vectorised solution, e.g. `(a < b).sum(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use direct array comparison and sum them along rows as:

```
(a<b).sum(axis=1)

array([0, 1, 0])

a<b
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
```

Comment: thank you for answering!! But maybe I didn't make it clear, what I want is,for example,all the elements in b's first row only compare with a's first row first elements.And b's second row elements compare with a's second row first elements,like this````